# How is the GetEnumerator method get invoked in a foreach loop in C#?

Tags: c#, collections, foreach, iterator

I was going through Iterator pattern and got a little confused when i stumpled upon logic i found in the sample code

```
class MonthCollection : IEnumerable
        {

          public string[] months = {
"January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
"July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"};

            public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
            {
                // Generates values from the collection
                foreach (string element in months)
                    yield return element;
            }
        }

        static void Main()
        {

            MonthCollection collection = new MonthCollection();
            // Consumes values generated from collection's GetEnumerator method
            foreach (string n in collection)
                Console.Write(n + " ");
            Console.WriteLine("\n");
        }
```

in this code, the normal way to access the Array to strings would be to call the months variable like this in the foreach statement

**MonthCollection collection = new MonthCollection();

foreach (string n in collection.months){ }**

> but i could not understand how is the foreach getting access to the
>   collection without even calling the months variable directly

**MonthCollection collection = new MonthCollection();

            foreach (string n in collection){}**

**UPDATE 1**

what i couldnt understand is how can i access the variable months without calling it like this in the above class

```
static void Main()
        {

            MonthCollection collection = new MonthCollection();
            // Consumes values generated from collection's GetEnumerator method
            foreach (string n in collection.months)
                Console.Write(n + " ");
            Console.WriteLine("\n");
        }
```

instead of like this

```
 MonthCollection collection = new MonthCollection();
               method
                foreach (string n in collection)
                    Console.Write(n + " ");
                Console.WriteLine("\n");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`foreach` loop does not require a collection, all it needs is a an object with a `GetEnumerator()` method returning `IEnumerator`, which in your case comes with `IEnumerable` implementation.

C# compiler produces the remaining "magic" - a hidden temporary variable to reference the enumerator object, the code to start enumeration, the code to get each item, and the code to see when enumeration is over.

In your case C# relies on your implementation to get to the content of the `months` array using another piece of "magic" - the `yield return` construct. This construct lets you implement `GetEnumerator()` without writing a separate class for it. The construct is converted to a class with a state machine, letting you "return" objects from the middle of a loop, and then restart back where it was when the next item is requested from the iterator.

The objects returned from `yield return` do not have to come from a collection. You can even mix objects from a collection with other objects, for example

```
public IEnumerator GetEnumerator() {
    // Generates values from the collection
    foreach (string element in months) {
        yield return element + " will start soon!";
        yield return element;
        yield return element + " has ended.";
    }
}
```

`foreach` loop access variable `months` indirectly, through your code that implements `GetEnumerator()`.

Comment: you mean to say the c# complier automatically calls the GetEnumerator() method if it is found in a class without requirng the user to call the variable explicitly.
for instance, if i have a public property in Class A and if i want to call the public property in then i would call like this
new A().Name;
but there is no need to call the GetEnumerator() method explicitly and it is all done by the C# complier, right?

Comment: @LijinJohn C# compiler requires the object on the right side of `in` be an implementation of `IEnumerable`, otherwise it is a compile-time error. `foreach` gets enumerator through `GetEnumerator()`, because it knows that the type check has been successful. This is part of C# "magic" that uses library-defined classes in code generation.

Comment: well my question is, in this eaxmple
 MonthCollection collection = new MonthCollection();
           
            foreach (string n in collection)
                Console.Write(n + " ");
            Console.WriteLine("\n");

i have not called the GetEnumerator() method i just call the object then how is the foreach loop get access to the collections?

Comment: according to my understanding it should be like this
foreach(var d in new MonthCollection().GetEnumerator())
or like this
foreach(var d in new MonthCollection().months)

Comment: @LijinJohn Your understanding is not correct. `month` is a collection. It is *allowed* to be used in `foreach`, the thing that you enumerate it is not *required* to be a collection. It can be any class that implements `IEnumerable`, such as your `MonthCollection`. Make a modification to your code the way I show in the edit to see how `yield return` mixes in not stored objects with stored.

Comment: It does not need to implement `IEnumerable` to be used in `foreach`. `public TSomething GetEnumerator()` where `TSomething` have `public TElement Current { get; }` and `public bool MoveNext()` is enough for `foreach` to work.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight thank you very much sir, i helped me to undestand it better